# automatically new line in .net textbox

Tags: .net, textbox, managed-c++

I use managed c++ on .net framework.
I want to add a text box and I request a sentence from the user. The text box shows the sentence. If the sentence is too long, it must pass the new line automatically.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the text inside the textbox should wrap around then set the [`WordWrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property of the `TextBox` to true.

Comment: No, I want to do it like powerpoint. For example in powerpoint, the program gives you a textbox to enter the caption. If the caption is too long, it automatically pass the new line.